# Why does the class that implements the interface have @Data and@Accessors(chain = true) that need to override the set method but not the get method?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an interface

```java
public interface IBaseHistory {
    String getCoId();
    void setPhysicalData(PhysicalData physicalData);
}
```

And a class that implements it,

```java
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class FunctionHistory  implements Serializable, IBaseHistory {
    private String coId;
    private PhysicalData physicalData;
}
```

Which says:

```
entity.FunctionHistory is not abstract and does not override the abstract method setPhysicalData(service.IBaseHistory.entity.PhysicalData)
```

I deleted the setPhysicalData method and the program was able to compile.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue

Comment: is there any chance of using `PhysicalData` from different packages? additionally, check if you have any special lombok configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `@Accessors(chain = true)`. With that will Lombok generate this:

```java
public class FunctionHistory implements IBaseHistory {

   // fields

   public FunctionHistory setPhysicalData(PhysicalData physicalData) {
      this.physicalData = physicalData;
      return this;
   }

   // some more
}
```

This is not matching your interface.

And here are some options:

1. Remove `@Accessors(chain = true)`
2. Change the interface
3. Put `@Accessors(chain = false)` onto your field.

And here are the related Lombok docs:
https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors

Comment: I solved the problem in the way you described，Thanks a lot  for clarifying this out